# "Undefined reference to" when using g++ and ncurses for compiling

Tags: ubuntu, g++, ncurses

I am having some difficulty compiling a program with g++ on Ubuntu and my suspicion is that the ncurses library is not running correctly I am fairly certain the problem isn't with the makefile but here it is:

```
GCC=g++

all::   TABARI
@ echo "All done in `pwd`"

coder.o : coder.cp TABARI.h memory.o parser.cp process.cp codes.cp 
$(GCC) -c coder.cp

memory.o: memory.cp TABARI.h parser.cp input.cp 
$(GCC) -c memory.cp

input.o : input.cp TABARI.h parser.o coder.o
$(GCC) -c input.cp

utilities.o : utilities.cp TABARI.h
$(GCC) -c utilities.cp

codes.o : codes.cp TABARI.h memory.o parser.cp process.cp 
$(GCC) -c codes.cp

output.o : output.cp TABARI.h memory.o input.o codes.o
$(GCC) -c output.cp

parser.o : parser.cp TABARI.h  memory.o process.o
$(GCC) -c parser.cp

process.o : process.cp TABARI.h memory.o parser.cp coder.o input.cp modify.o interface.o xmlinput.o
$(GCC) -c process.cp

interface.o : interface.cp TABARI.h
$(GCC) -c interface.cp

modify.o : modify.cp TABARI.h memory.o codes.o
    $(GCC) -c modify.cp

xmlinput.o : xmlinput.cp TABARI.h
    $(GCC) -c xmlinput.cp

TABARI.o : TABARI.cp TABARI.h interface.o process.o 
    $(GCC) -c TABARI.cp

TABARI: TABARI.o input.o memory.o utilities.o codes.o output.o coder.o parser.o\
 process.o interface.o modify.o xmlinput.o
    $(GCC) -lncurses -o TABARI.0.8.3b1 -g TABARI.o input.o memory.o utilities.o codes.o output.o coder.o parser.o\
 process.o interface.o modify.o xmlinput.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o 
    echo "Done..."
```

Whenever I run the make command I get a long string of

```
 undefined reference to `waddnstr'
 undefined reference to `stdscr'
 undefined reference to `waddch'
 undefined reference to `stdscr'
 undefined reference to `waddch'
 In function `ModifyClass::setupChange()':
 undefined reference to `stdscr'
 undefined reference to `whline'
 undefined reference to `move'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(GCC) -lncurses -o TABARI.0.8.3b1 -g TABARI.o input.o memory.o ...
```

Your libraries option (`-lncurses`) should be placed *after* all `.o` files, not before. Otherwise linking may (and seemingly in this case does) fail.

```
$(GCC) -o TABARI.0.8.3b1 -g TABARI.o input.o memory.o ... xmlinput.o -lncurses
```

Comment: Hooray new binutils. `</sarcasm>`